# jquery syntax help processing ajax data

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have two `form` tags. The second one pre-populates with options depending on the choice made in the first one, by making an Ajax request.

The data is returning perfectly and actually pre-populates the second `form` if I pass an example of some returned data to a local variable (see commented line).

Any advice would be appreciated as I am very new to JavaScript and am probably missing something blatantly obvious! I am using the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#table').change(function() {
        $.getJSON("/ajax_get", {
            id : $(this).val(),
            ajax : 'true'
        }, function(data) {
            /*
            var data = [
                { 
                    "optionValue":"actor_id", 
                    "optionDisplay": "actor_id"
                },
                {
                    "optionValue":"film_id", 
                    "optionDisplay": "film_id"
                },
                {
                    "optionValue":"priority", 
                    "optionDisplay": "priority"
                }
            ];
            */
            var $persons = $('#fields').empty();
            $.each(data, function() {
                $persons.append("<option value=" + this.optionValue + ">" + this.optionDisplay + "</option>");
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Run `console.log(data)` in the callback - is the data what you expect?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure where to place console.log(data), but I am using Firebug/Firequery and the data is returned in exactly the format of the commented var line.

Comment: You should make a question or outline the actual problem so it is clear what you need help doing.

Comment: If you just want us to review your code, you need to post it on codereview.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: Thanks Andrey, I have posted the code up there for review as well.

Answer (score 0):

You're using jQuery so `this` needs to be `$(this)`:

```
$.each(data, function() {
    $persons.append("<option value=" + $(this).optionValue + ">" + $(this).optionDisplay + "</option>");
});
```

Comment: Thanks Valjas, but that didn't work.I just can't work out why the loop works with the data represented as a variable but not with the returned data object.

Comment: Try adding an element in the function(). So $.each(data, function(item) then call item.optionValue, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I've learn't a valuable lesson in making absolutely sure of JSON syntax.It ended up being an extra comma in the returned data (caused by the way I manipulated the data in a loop) making it an invalid JSON response.The JQuery loop and placement of the form options was fine but the invalid JSON data caused the script to fail silently.
Thanks to those that gave advice.Cheers.